# Dynamically add TextView to Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to add TextView dynamically in the following way. But not able to see my new TextView after I run the app.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    TextView textView= (TextView) new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hello");
    textView.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
    textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(textView);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.LinearLayout1);
    vg.invalidate();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
    try {
        databaseHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    databaseHelper.openDataBase();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after I deleting the xml and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.LinearLayout1);
vg.invalidate();
```

Comment: Removed these 2 lines. Still do not see "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

After adding the textview to linearlayout request the layout as follows

```
ll.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);
tv.setText("test");
this.linerLayout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: What is here this? Is it current context or view? I am new to android dev. this. shows only methods.

Comment: this is always give context of current class.